# ms access run-time error -2147352567 (80020009) the data has been changed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Been getting the above error all of a sudden in an Access DB I'm building.  It triggers in a proc that I haven't edited in a while.  Was working fine.  The strange thing is, when the error triggers and I go into debug mode, I can immediately continue running the code and it works.  I tried putting a pause in before that line runs, but it didn't seem to help.

Here's a segment of the code, however, this proc generally just calls other procs:

```
    Call common.CalculateAllLoadTotals(Me, Me.AffiliateID, Me.ClientID, Me.FacilityID, Me.ProposalRevision)

'    Call common_2.sSleep(2000)

    Me.chkProposalRevisionTreated = -1
    Me.txtTreated.Requery
```

The error highlights the following line:

```
Me.chkProposalRevisionTreated = -1
```

Any thoughts?

Scotty

Comment: I'm not sure what a ghost break point is.  You can have break points that you can't see? Anyway, I'm actually receiving an error (see subject)

Comment: Tried that and also a Compact & Repair.  Didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I had this problem when Access tries to save data to a linked table (gotten from sql) which it cannot write to directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I "solved" my issue with a different approach.  No big deal really, but I used an SQL UPDATE query to change the value.  It's very strange.

Anyway, I'd still welcome anyone's insight into this issue.

Scotty